# Javascript dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have a small function that can change the type of a form input (I use it to change a button to submit). I've found it somewhere and didn't write it myself, it's just a small, handy Little piece of code, like this:

```
function change_input_type(id,x)
{
    var id;
    var x;

    // Change input type
    document.getElementById(id).type = x;
}
```

And I call it using onClick:

```
onClick="change_input_type('myButton','submit');
```

But I want it to also be able to change the value of an input (another hidden input that I want to change from 0 to 1 in some cases). I know I can create another function, rename it to change_input_value and then change document.getElementById(id).**type** to document.getElementById(id).**value** but I want a generic funtion, like this:

```
function change_input(id,x,y)
{
    var id;
    var x;
    var y;

    // Change input
    document.getElementById(id).x = y;
}
```

And onClick like this:

```
onClick="change_input('myButton','type','submit');"
onClick="change_input('myHidden','value','1');"
```

But when I try that it wont work. I usually work with php and I'm not very skilled with JavaScript... so I wonder what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have the possibilty in your project to use jQuery. Often it is more easier to set DOM properties/values with this library. Especially if you are new to JS

Comment: @Tushar Beside that it is not overwritten in Chrome and FF, are you sure that it should behave that way? The `var` statement just binds the name to the scope of the function, like a parameter does.

Comment: @t.niese No, that doesn't overwrite the params. My mistake.

Comment: IMO for such a trivial operation there's little need for a specialized function (especially since that function is also clearly written by someone who doesn't understand Javascript very much; the `var` declarations are entirely superfluous). Just write `document.get...` directly as needed when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing object property via `[..]` (bracket notation) will let you use variable's value as property name.

```
document.getElementById(id)[x] = y;
```

Check [MDN Property accessor - bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `setAttribute()` method to set the value of attribute named `x` to `y`

```
// Change input type
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute(x, y);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: It should be mentioned that `setAttribute` will not necessarily have a directly noticeable effect. E.g. changing the `value` attribute if the `value` property was already changed. Attributes should more be seen as default values then live values (properties). And w3schools is into the best reference they introduce setAttribute with the exactly those attributes where you normally should not use it.